# Signing commits with Git doesn't ask for my passphrase

Tags: git, gnupg, sign, gpg-agent

I was trying to sign my commits with the command `git commit -S` but it fails without prompting my passphrase for my GPG key.

The error is:

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I noticed that if I run the following command before `git commit -S`:

```
gpg -o /dev/null --local-user MY_KEY_ID -as <(echo 1234) && echo "The correct passphrase was entered for this key"
```

...everything works well and my commits are properly signed. I think it's because my passphrase is cached but this is not the behaviour that I expect.

I was hoping that Git would prompt for my passphrase everytime I want to sign commits or tags.

The command to "unlock my key" was found on this question: [How to use gpg command-line to check passphrase is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381123/how-to-use-gpg-command-line-to-check-passphrase-is-correct)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You likely need to tell `pinentry`, the software gpg uses to prompt for your password, where to prompt you.

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
git commit -S
```

If this works I would recommend exporting `GPG_TTY` in your shell's 'rc' file.

[gpg-agent documentation regarding `GPG_TTY`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html)

Comment: It works like a charm, have you some documentation that i've missed about this ?

Comment: Edited my answer to add some gpg documentation.  Actually, I had this same problem while setting up signed commits for my git profile.  It doesn't seem to be documented very well from the git side.

Comment: This solution also works if you're getting this error when you login to a machine via SSH that you usually access via a keyboard/mouse with a GUI - e.g. Ubuntu Desktop (20.04 in my case).

Answer (score 1):

For me, unsetting and setting again the signing key worked like a charm.

This works either if you are changing the signing key for another one or git suddenly stopped prompting for the passphrase.

```
// remove signing key
git config --unset user.signingkey

// add new signing key
git config user.signingkey SECRETKEYLONGID

// tell git to automatically sign every commit
git config commit.gpgsign true

// commit as usual
git commit -m "commit message"
```

Git [explains](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key#telling-git-about-your-gpg-key-2) hot to get the signing key long ID.

That's it!. I hope it comes handy.